# Entire block of a HTML is not receiving CSS class style

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML section with `class="hero"` and the CSS `.hero` to style it, however, the background colour seems to only be being applied to the `<h1>` element located in the `<section class="hero">` section. It is not being applied to the `<p>` tags or `<a>` tags located in the same section. Please help.

```css
/*-----------------------------------------
GENERAL
------------------------------------------*/
.wrap{
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



/*-----------------------------------------
NAV
------------------------------------------*/





/*-----------------------------------------
HERO
------------------------------------------*/
.hero {
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    height: 20px;
}


/*-----------------------------------------
MAIN SECTION
------------------------------------------*/




/*-----------------------------------------
FOOTER
------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!--HERO SECTION-->
<section class="hero">
  <h1>Welcome to Foundation 6</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pharetra lobortis ligula, a porttitor sem porttitor consequat. Vestibulum ac massa non lorem cursus sodales. Fusce convallis nisl ex, a iaculis eros pulvinar id. Vestibulum consectetur eget augue convallis bibendum. Fusce tempus consectetur risus ac interdum. Aenean eu lacus eu metus egestas feugiat. Suspendisse sed venenatis metus, at lacinia elit. Praesent tristique placerat lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In ullamcorper velit leo, quis interdum sapien dapibus non. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed suscipit massa eget mauris dictum, ut malesuada felis pulvinar. </p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Learn more</a>
    <a href="#" class="success button">Contact Us</a>
</section>
```

Comment: The height is too low. `20px` doesn't allow for the content inside http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyaBgQ

Answer (score 2):

The background color extends only as far as the height specified. Remove that and the background color will be applied to the whole hero section.

Change this:

```
.hero {
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    height: 20px; <<-- REMOVE THIS
}
```

To this:

```
.hero {
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 80px 0px;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/189/